# Need some JQuery or javascript code to scroll to the 1st result after a page search using contains()

Tags: jquery, scroll, contains

I have a page search in development here on the Table of Contents tab: http://www.vpgmarketresearch.com/tabs.html.  I am looking for a way to scroll the window to the first result found from the search. For example, if you search for "Spain" there are 109 results. I'd like to take the user to the first one.

I've read all the similar questions, nothing relevant.

You can see all the code by viewing source. Disregard the ugly inline CSS for this very big page. That is temporary.

Here is the code that contains the "contains" and I think this is what needs to be adjusted:

```
$('div.TabbedPanelsContent :contains("'+term+'")').each(function(){  
$(this).html($(this).html().replace(new RegExp(term,'g'), '<span class="highlight">'+term+'</span>'));  
$(this).find('span.highlight').fadeIn("slow");
```

Here is where I got this bit of search code: http://www.ryancoughlin.com/2008/12/20/jquery-search-and-highlight/

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've hard coded the term so replace that with your own implementation:

```
var term = 'Encephalitis';

$('div.TabbedPanelsContent :contains("'+term+'")').each(function(){ 
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(new RegExp(term,'g'), '<span class="highlight">'+term+'</span>'));  
  $(this).find('span.highlight').fadeIn("slow"); var offset = $(this).offset().top;
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: offset
  }, 100);
  return false;
});
```

You can adjust the 100 ms delay to longer or shorter. The return false is important as it breaks the iterator. If you don't the page will scroll to each match of the term instead of the first found.

Comment: Thanks Jake, works great! One weird anomaly I don't get. When I use it to search a Country name it doesn't scroll, like "Spain" or "Italy". Any thoughts on why that is? [link](http://www.vpgmarketresearch.com/tabs.html)

Comment: Jake, correction...it doesn't work at all in IE. :/ (like everything else!)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a cool smooth transition like this:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
```

This will scroll to the top of the page, (0 is y-the coordinate of the top)

To go to the first result, you could replace the 0:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#first_result").offset().top }, "slow");
```

Or, you could use the [scrollTo plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo).

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Edgar: Jake's version above does not work in IE. Any suggestions?  Thanks!